# My three children define me

Tags: riddle

My three children define me.
Without them I am nothing.
My most active child is constantly busy.
My second child stays the same but is always growing.
I just don't know about my third child.

Who am I?

Comment: +1.  This might be better:  "My most active child is constantly busy."  "My second child stays the same but is always growing." and "And I just don't know about my third child".  I would swap the first and second children because the one has to come before the other.

Comment: @BGM  I really like your suggestions so the riddle has been revised accordingly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer:

> Father Time

The three children are:

> Past time, Present time, and Future time

Explanation:

Without them I am nothing:

> Father Time cannot exist without time itself.

My most active child is a doer:

> The Present is always working

My third child is a mystery:

> The Future is a mystery to everyone

My first child is the opposite of the third:

> The Past has already happened; the Future has not.

Comment: Bravo!  This was solved much faster than I thought.